# Spring 3 security is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to build an application for get to now spring 3. I now try to configure security but it seems that my fitlers are getting picked up.

below is my web.xml file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    Prime Pedigrees

```
<description>Pedigree Application</description>
<!--
    Key of the system property that should specify the root directory of this
    web app. Applied by WebAppRootListener or Log4jConfigListener.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>pedigree.root</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--
    Location of the Log4J config file, for initialization and refresh checks.
    Applied by Log4jConfigListener.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--
    - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
    - Applied by ContextLoaderServlet.
    -
    - Can be set to:
    - "/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml" for the Hibernate implementation,
    - "/WEB-INF/applicationContext-jpa.xml" for the JPA one, or
    - "/WEB-INF/applicationContext-jdbc.xml" for the JDBC one.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--
        To use the JPA variant above, you will need to enable Spring load-time
        weaving in your server environment. Out of the box, Spring will try to
        detect the running environment and use the appropriate weaver but if that
        fails, one must enable one by hand or use the VM-wide weaver.
        See PetClinic's readme and/or Spring's JPA documentation for more information.
    -->


    <!-- ****************************************** -->


    <!--
    - Configures Log4J for this web app.
    - As this context specifies a context-param "log4jConfigLocation", its file path
    - is used to load the Log4J configuration, including periodic refresh checks.
    -
    - Would fall back to default Log4J initialization (non-refreshing) if no special
    - context-params are given.
    -
    - Exports a "web app root key", i.e. a system property that specifies the root
    - directory of this web app, for usage in log file paths.
    - This web app specifies "petclinic.root" (see log4j.properties file).
-->
<!-- Leave the listener commented-out if using JBoss -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    <!--
    - Loads the root application context of this web app at startup,
    - by default from "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml".
    - Note that you need to fall back to Spring's ContextLoaderServlet for
    - J2EE servers that do not follow the Servlet 2.4 initialization order.
    -
    - Use WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
    - to access it anywhere in the web application, outside of the framework.
    -
    - The root context is the parent of all servlet-specific contexts.
    - This means that its beans are automatically available in these child contexts,
    - both for getBean(name) calls and (external) bean references.
-->
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>

 <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/resources/images</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>jpg
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>tcdefault</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

    <!--
    Defines the 'default' servlet (usually for service static resources).
    Uncomment this in containers (GlassFish) that do not declare this 
    implicit definition out of the box, or change the name of the servlet mapping 
    below to the appropriate one.

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
-->
<!--
 - Map static resources to the default servlet
 - examples:
 -     http://localhost:8080/static/images/pets.png
 -     http://localhost:8080/static/styles/petclinic.css
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> -->

<!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    - Has its own application context, by default defined in "{servlet-name}-servlet.xml",
    - i.e. "petclinic-servlet.xml".
    -
    - A web app can contain any number of such servlets.
    - Note that this web app has a shared root application context, serving as parent
    - of all DispatcherServlet contexts.
-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>pedigree</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <!--
    - Maps the petclinic dispatcher to "*.do". All handler mappings in
    - petclinic-servlet.xml will by default be applied to this subpath.
    - If a mapping isn't a /* subpath, the handler mappings are considered
    - relative to the web app root.
    -
    - NOTE: A single dispatcher can be mapped to multiple paths, like any servlet.
-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pedigree</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>pedigree</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <!-- Displays a stack trace -->
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- eliminate welcome files -->
<!-- useful for Servlet 3 container (Tomcat 7 and Jetty 6) -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!--
    - Reference to PetClinic database.
    - Only needed if not using a local DataSource but a JNDI one instead.
-->
<!--
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/petclinic</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
-->
```

This is my appicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

They are both in the web-inf folder of the application. The application is deployed using tomcat 6. According to the manual of spring security, after the above I should not be able to access anything before logging in. BUT i can access everything without even being asked to login.

Could someone help please?

Every tip appreciated.

Thanks,
john.

Answer (score 0):

ok it was my stupid mistake.

inside web.xml i had:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

so this means i did not close the context-param properly.

now my web.xml part file looks like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

thans